# IntelliJ "Unexpected symbol" error for elvis op used on a new line

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, static-analysis

Following groovy code triggers an Error in IDEA: "Unexpected symbol: ; or newline expected"

```
final project = 'foo'
?: 'bar'
```

[image]

I tried running it in https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and locally and the code executes OK.

The question is: is it a bug in IDEA or is groovy runtime accepting invalid code?

- IDEA 2018.1.3
- Groovy 2.4.15

Comment: Looks like an old bug in IntelliJ IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152633.

Comment: care to post it as an answer to be accepted?

Comment: I would say it's vague as to whether this is invalid or not... the first line is complete in and of itself.   If you were to type `final int x = 10` on one line and `+ 20` on the next line...  x would be 10, not 30.   It's only the fact that a statement can't start with Elvis that gives any indication you mean it to be a continuation.

Comment: Groovy has no formal specification so everything is vague. Yet I fail to see how is this relevant -- IDEA should not flag code that Groovy accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152633) in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to [watch/vote](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135).